# Como renderizar eventos no FullCalendar por views específicas?

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

Imagine a seguinte situação: Tenho 2 arrays e duas views no meu fullCalendar.

**Na view "list" preciso renderizar o primeiro array de eventos**, que reflete o select em uma view no banco de dados. **Esse eventos vêm em branco**, e quando preenchidos num modal são cadastrados e **param em outra tabela**, que por sua vez eu faço um select e **armazeno o resultado num outro array, que será renderizado na view "month"**

*meu código fica assim*

```
//array de teste que vem de uma função do php
            <?php
        $dadosDaTabela = \App\Models\AgendasMedicas::GetAllofThisDataAgenda($doctorVal);
        foreach ($dadosDaTabela as $value) {
            ?> {
//o conteudo aqui nao interessa, o importante pra mim é ver se alguma coisa é retornada
                            id: '<?php echo $value['DT_CONSULTA_AGENDADA']; ?>',
                            title: '<?php echo $value['DT_CONSULTA_AGENDADA']; ?>',
                            color: 'red',
                            start: '<?php echo $value['DT_CONSULTA_AGENDADA']; ?>',

                        },
        <?php }
        ?>
                ];

//no meu full calendar, tento isto: 
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    viewRender: function (view, element) {
                        if (view.name == 'list') {
//aqui meu array é renderizado, o problema é que ele se renderiza nas outras views também...
                            events: events_array
                        }
                        if (view.name == 'month') {
                            alert('month')
                        }
                        if (view.name == 'agendaWeek') {
                            alert('agendaWeek')
                        }
                    },
                    timezone: 'America/Sao_Paulo',
                    header: {
                        left: ' prev title next ',
                        right: 'list,agendaWeek,month'
                    },
                    buttonText: {
                        list: 'Hoje',
                        listWeek: 'Semana'
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Verifica se o atributo `id` dos elementos não é o mesmo, talvez postar o HTML possa ajudar a solucionar o problema.

Comment: O FullCalendar é montado através apenas de uma div com o id "calendar"... não tem mais do que isso no meu HTML.

Comment: O id dos elementos não pode ser o mesmo, Leonardo, porque eu atribuo a eles data e hora, portanto é impossível de ser igual.

Comment: Então você tem apenas um calendário e quer mudar os eventos de acordo com a view selecionada?

Comment: Exatamente, eu tenho 2 arrays em javascript que são alimentados com foreachs do php, e gostaria que numa view o meu array 1 de eventos fosse carregado, e em outra view, o array 2 fosse carregado

Answer (score 1):

Depois de bater muito a cabeça e ler muito a documentação, eu consegui finalmente.
Estou usando a versão 3 do fullCalendar, o código final ficou desta forma:

```
//meus arrays (virtual e scheduled)
                    var virtual_array = [

        <?php
        $virtualArrays = \App\Models\AgendasMedicas::GetAllofThisDataAgenda($doctorVal);
        foreach ($virtualArrays as $virtualArray) {
            ?> {
                            id: '<?php echo $virtualArray['DT_CONSULTA_AGENDADA']; ?>',
                            title: '<?php echo $virtualArray['DT_CONSULTA_AGENDADA']; ?>',
                            color: 'red',
                            start: '<?php echo $virtualArray['DT_CONSULTA_AGENDADA']; ?>',

                   },
        <?php }
        ?>
                ];

                var scheduled_array = [

        <?php
        $scheduledArrays = \App\Models\AgendasMedicas::GetAllofThisDataAgendada();
        foreach ($scheduledArrays as $scheduledArray) {
            ?> {
                            id: '<?php echo $scheduledArray['DT_CONSULTA_AGENDADA']; ?>',
                            title: '<?php echo $scheduledArray['DT_CONSULTA_AGENDADA']; ?>',
                            color: 'red',
                            start: '<?php echo $scheduledArray['DT_CONSULTA_AGENDADA']; ?>',

                        },
        <?php }
        ?>
                ];

// e o meu fullCalendar ficou da seguinte forma:

          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    viewRender: function(view, element){

                        if(view.name == 'list'){
                          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', virtual_array);
                          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
                        }
                        if(view.name == 'month'){
                             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', scheduled_array);
                             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
                        }
                        if(view.name == 'agendaWeek'){
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', scheduled_array);
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
                        }
                    },
//restante do calendario........
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mudar os eventos você deve remover os existentes depois inserir os novos

Eu uso `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');` para remover os eventos e atualizá-los.

Montei um exemplo com seu código

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
                    if (view.name == 'list') {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                        events: events_array
                    }
                    if (view.name == 'month') {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                        events: novo_events_array
                    }
                    if (view.name == 'agendaWeek') {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                        events: outro_events_array
                    }
                },
```

Assim a cada vez que a view for alterada, os novos dados serão carregados.

Comment: Eu não precisaria de atualizar? Testei aqui e não rodou, na verdade, quando o meu segundo array é construído - sem chamar ele no fullCalendar, a syntax highlight já quebra, é como se ele não reconhecesse a existência do segundo array. No console acusa erro de sintaxe, mas tá tudo correto e eu já chequei um milhão de vezes, talvez seja algum bug por conta do php, não sei. Mas enfim, a sua solução me parece razoável, mas ocorre que quando mudo de uma view para outra e volto para a anterior, tudo some e fica assim... preciso atualizar? e como fazer isso caso precise?

Comment: Eu atualizo com ajax, depois de remover os eventos e faço uma requisição ajax e busco as novas informações para popular os evento. Você pode também separar a responsabilidade de criar o array da sua view, passando para um controller por exemplo e mandando o array montado para a view. Posta o erro do console também, talvez ajude a resolver o problema. Talvez iterando os eventos e usando `$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', evento, true);` possa resolver o problema

Comment: Você esta usando algum framework?

Comment: Já publiquei a resposta, Leonardo. Valeu!